# Coefficient of the three-point function of two identical scalars and stress tensor in CFT in $D>2$

Tags: conformal-field-theory, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, correlation-functions, ads-cft

The three-point function of two scalars with a spin-$l$ tensor is given by

$$ \langle \phi_{1}(x_1) \phi_{2}(x_2) J^{\mu_1 ...\mu_l}(x_3) \rangle = f_{\phi \phi J} \frac{(Z^{\mu_1}...Z^{\mu_l}-\text{traces})}{x_{12}^{\Delta_1+\Delta_2-\Delta_3+l} x_{13}^{\Delta_1+\Delta_3-\Delta_2-l} x_{23}^{\Delta_2+\Delta_3-\Delta_1-l}}, $$

with

$$ Z^{\mu} = \frac{x_{13}^{\mu}}{x_{13}^2} - \frac{x_{23}^{\mu}}{x_{23}^2}.$$

Accordingly, the three-point function of two identical scalars and the stress tensor is given by

$$ \langle \phi(x_1) \phi(x_2) T^{\mu \nu}(x_3) \rangle = f_{\phi \phi T} \frac{(Z^{\mu}Z^{\nu}-\frac{\delta^{\mu \nu}}{d}Z_{\rho} Z^{\rho})}{x_{12}^{2\Delta_{\phi}-d+2} x_{13}^{d-2} x_{23}^{d-2}}.$$

Many CFT papers now simply state that the coefficient is fixed by a conformal Ward identity, leading to  $$ f_{\phi \phi T} = -\frac{d}{d-1}\frac{\Delta_{\phi}}{\text{vol}(S^{d-1})},$$

$S^{d-1}$ being the unit sphere in $d-1$ dimensions.

I tried using the integrated Ward identity (eq. 1.39 from the EPFL Lectures on Conformal Field Theory in D > 3 Dimensions by Slava Rychkova)

$$ \int_{S^{d-1}} dS_{\mu} \langle T^{\mu \nu}(x) \phi(x_1) \phi(x_2) \rangle = \langle \partial^{\nu} \phi(x_1) \phi(x_2) \rangle$$

to retrieve the expression - so far I've been unsuccessful.

I would be happy if someone could give me a hint regarding the approach.